# How to enable presigned S3 URL for different users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am trying to build a service where users are able to upload photos to an S3 database using presigned URLs given to them via API gateway. For each user, I was planning on submitting the photo information through the presigned URL and identifying the user who sent it as metadata via the ID found in the access token granted by AWS Cognito.

However, I am not sure how to secure it so that users can only upload photos as themselves and not as others. It seems to me that malicious users can simply modify the frontend code to change the user ID and submit photos as someone else.

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a presigned URL with some sort of ID so that they can only submit content as themselves? Or is there a better way?

Comment: `Or is there a better way` A great alternative is to [directly upload to S3 using temporary credentials issued by Cognito](https://medium.com/tensult/s3-direct-upload-with-cognito-authentication-56a5c0ff4916). This way there's no need for Lambda or custom presinging routines. You do have to pay the cost for the Cognito Service is perhaps the only downside.

Answer (score 2):

How about this solution:-
There is one question that is not mentioned, how do you plan to differentiate legit users and non-legit users, or is it open to everyone?

- Use Amazon Cognito to authenticate users.
- users will try to query for URL (upload s3 through an interface), API gateway will verify authentication.
- if authentication is successful; then only lambda will generate an s3 resigned URL.

This solution is a little costly however it serves you the purpose of making it secure, where if the user is authenticated then only lambda will generate a signed URL.

You should not worry about the identity of the user, or someone sending a false identity, because a sub claim will be present as part of the token, if someone tries to change that, the cognito will not verify it.

- A heads up:- if you are trying to make this service global, then you can implement a backend database like dynamodb, and add a manual/automatic step to add a attribute to identity users who are privileged and add logic to lambda to find users who is privileged and then generate resigned URL exclusively for that privileged user

.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html

Comment: I am using AWS Cognito to generate JWT tokens. My concern isn't that someone will try and alter the token, it's mainly how to associate the right user with the photo upload. My concern is that:

1) Someone will sign up for a legitimate account.
2) They will receive access tokens associated with their account, and hence get a signed URL for uploading.
3) They will change the frontend code so that when they upload, the metadata will contain a different user ID than the one from the token.
4) This will be uploaded to S3 through the signed URL.

Comment: Okay so the real question is how do you identify the user who is uploading the photo, the title is little ambiguous, anyways, for this you can have a dynamodb, when user registers there info will be stored in dynamodb. Now user tries to authenticate, lambda which is generating presigned url will check dynamodb with their token identifier.if they are both same then it will try to generate presigned url. You can generate pre signed url based on this value which is inside token, so on this solution you won't rely on frontend to store metadata

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html#s3-create-presigendurl-put  Even in this example we can alter creation on bucket name, so based on the value of token and db check you can generate a dynamic name for the bucket this way you  don't have to worry about user identification

Comment: did the solution helped?